# Refactor duplicate methods with generics

Tags: c#, generics, refactoring

I have some methods. How I can refactor this code to have generic method?

First method:

```
    void ChangeProjectName(DataModel dataModel)
    { 
        foreach (Project project in dataModel.Projects)
        {
            string projectName = project.Name;
            projectName = ChangeName(projectName);

            project.Name = projectName;
        }

        dataModel.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

Second method:

```
    void ChangeEmployeeName(DataModel dataModel)
    {
        foreach (Employee employee in dataModel.Employees)
        {
            string employeeName = employee.Name;
            employeeName = ChangeName(employeeName);

            employee.Name = employeeName;
        }

        dataModel.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

We must be able to get the `T` type collection from the appropriate property in the model, so we must pass a selection strategy for it:

```
void ChangeName<T>(DataModel dataModel,
                   Func<DataModel, IEnumerable<T>> selector)
    where T : IHaveName
{ 
    foreach (T x in selector(dataModel))
    {
        x.Name = ChangeName(x.Name);
    }

    dataModel.SubmitChanges();
}
```

and usage:

```
ChangeName(model, x => x.Projects);
```

You can add an `Action<T>` parameter and pass it `x => x.Name = ChangeName(x.Name)` if you want to avoid having the `IHaveName` interface (or base class, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better if seperate changing name from submitting data.

```
void ChangeName<T>(IEnumerable<T> list) where T : IHaveName
{ 
    foreach (T item in list)
    {
        item.Name = ChangeName(project.Name);
    }
}

void ChangeNamesAndSubmitChanges(dataModel dataModel)
{ 
    ChangeName(dataModel.Projects);
    ChangeName(dataModel.Employees);
    dataModel.SubmitChanges();
}
```

or create ChangeNamesAndSubmitChanges with delegate as proposed by Yorye Nathan.

Comment: I agree. I would prefer to have the `ChangeMethod` only change the name, and call `SubmitChanges` in the appropriate places higher on the stack.

Comment: Your `foreach` loop should be using `T` as the type instead of `Project`.